# A sequence of functions converging to the Dirac delta

Tags: convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

let $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}n $ for $|x|<\frac{1}{n}$ and  for positive integer n.  Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)=\delta(x)$$

Pretty evident after a quick sketch, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Are you sure you are stating the problem correctly? $g_n(x)$ does not seem to depend on $x$ at all but only on $n$. Please restate the problem

Comment: Oh yea, forgot the bounds.

Comment: I assume that it should be $n \to \infty$

Comment: With the correction that user44197 commented, this is usually how $\delta (x)$ is _defined_. You cannot prove a definition. For this question to have a meaningful answer (and be worth my vote back into non-negatives), you need to edit in the context of how $\delta (x)$ is being defined.

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is usually defined by its action as a kernal in integrals, i.e. by the relationship $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) f(x) dx = f(0)$ for any function continuous at zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a typo in the question. Should be $n \to \infty$

Let $f(x)$ be any function that is continuous in the neighborhood of $0$. Suppose that $n$ is large enough so that $|x| < 1/n$ is inside this interval.
Then
$$
\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} g_n(x) f(x) = \int_{-\frac1n} ^{\frac1n} g_n(x) f(x) 
=\frac 1 2 n \int_{-\frac1n} ^{\frac1n} f(x)=\frac 1 2 n \cdot \left(
\frac 2 n f(\theta)\right)
$$
for some $\theta$ in the interval $[-1/n, 1/n]$.
As $n\to \infty$, $\theta$ gets squeezed to zero and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} g_n(x) f(x) = f(0)$$
which is the definition of the delta function.

Comment: I'm confused by why you don't integrate $f$? How is the integral of $f$ (even over that boundary) still $f$?

Comment: @FelicioGrande : The mean value theorem of integral calculus was used, this is how it was done.