# Show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 \frac n 2 e^{-n|x|}f(x)dx=f(0)$ if $f: [-1,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For a continuous function $f:[-1,1] \to \Bbb R$, show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 \frac n 2 e^{-n|x|}f(x)dx=f(0)$$

I showed this by given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. Then divide the integral into $[-\delta,\delta]$ and $[-1,1]-[-\delta,\delta]$ (as in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128863/9718)), and I think it works, although I will not write the details in here. But I'm curious that if there is a better proof. My proof seems elementary and a little messy.

Comment: Do you know Dirac delta function? See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662945/a-sequence-of-functions-converging-to-the-dirac-delta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $y = nx$, we arrive at
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-n}^n e^{-|y|} f(y/n)\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\int \chi_{[-n,n]}(y) e^{-|y|} f(y/n)\, dy,
$$
where $\chi_{[-n,n]}$ is the characteristic function/indicator function of the interval $[-n,n]$ and we have extended $f$ by $0$ to all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Now the integrand converges pointwise to $e^{-|y|}\cdot f(0)$, and is dominated (in absolute value) by the integrable function $y\mapsto e^{-|y|} \cdot \max_{x\in [-1,1]}|f(x)|$. Use the dominated convergence theorem (I hope you know it, otherwise this answer will not help you much) to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ \int_{-1}^{1}
     {n \over 2}\,\expo{-n\verts{x}}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x = \fermi\pars{0}:\
     {\large ?}.\qquad\fermi:\bracks{-1,1}\ \to\ {\mathbb R}\,,\quad\fermi}$
is continuous.

---

\begin{align}
\mbox{Note that}&\quad\dsc{\int_{-1}^{1}{n \over 2}\,\expo{-n\verts{x}}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x}
=\half\int_{-1}^{1}n\expo{-n\verts{x}}
\bracks{\fermi\pars{x} - \fermi\pars{0}}\,\dd x + \fermi\pars{0}
\\[5mm]&=\half\int_{-n}^{n}\expo{-\verts{x}}
\bracks{\fermi\pars{x \over n} - \fermi\pars{0}}\,\dd x + \fermi\pars{0}
\end{align}

> The whole problem is reduced to prove that
>   $\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ \half\int_{-n}^{n}\expo{-\verts{x}}
> \bracks{\fermi\pars{x \over n} - \fermi\pars{0}}\,\dd x = \dsc{0}}$.

---

Given $\ds{\epsilon > 0, \exists\ \delta > 0\ \mid\
\braces{~0 < \verts{x \over n} < \delta\ \imp\
\verts{\fermi\pars{x \over n} - \fermi\pars{0}} < 2\epsilon~}}$. Then,
$\ds{\exists\ N \equiv \floor{\verts{x} \over \delta}\ \mid\
\bracks{~n > N\ \imp\ \verts{\fermi\pars{x \over n} - \fermi\pars{0}} < 2\epsilon~}}$. It's true that

---

$$
\verts{\half\int_{-n}^{n}\expo{-\verts{x}}
\bracks{\fermi\pars{x \over n} - \fermi\pars{0}}\,\dd x}
<\pars{\half\int_{-n}^{n}\expo{-\verts{x}}\,\dd x}\epsilon < \epsilon\ \quad\mbox{when}\quad n > N
$$

> This completes the proof.